# How to get additional information about Facebook page fans beyond age, gender and location?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am successfully using the Facebook Graph API to get the basic information about page fans - age and gender distribution:
`https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE-ID/insights/page_fans_gender_age`

and location:
`https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE-ID/insights/page_fans_gender_city`

However, I am interested in acquiring more detailed information about page fans beyond these three metrics (age, gender, and location). For example, I would like to access data related to their interests, occupation, education level, etc.

The [Facebook graph API documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/insights/) does not provide any direct methods for retrieving such additional information.

I would appreciate your guidance on any alternative approaches or endpoints that could be used to access this desired data using the Facebook Graph API.